# A permutation that has even order in the symmetric group $S_n$ may be odd or even.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This statement is in Example 2.10.3 of Artin's Algebra. Can anyone give me an example of that? I tried a few permutations, but they don't satisfy the claim.

Comment: You need $n\ge4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of an $n$-cycle is $n$, but it breaks into a product of $n-1$ transpositions.

If $m$ is an even number, any $m$-cycle in $S_n$ has even order, but is an odd permutation.

On the other hand, the product of two disjoint $m$-cycles (in some $S_n$ where $n > 2m$) still has even order, but now is an even permutation.

Comment: I think you mean $n-1$ transpositions.

Comment: @FaqirChand yes, thanks! Fixing it now.